# Make passing an async function to filter a compile-time error

Tags: typescript, promise

I know that `files.filter(async file => await isDirectory(file))` doesn’t filter the array at all, because the async function returns a promise which has a truthy value as a boolean.

- [Filtering an array with a function that returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355528/filtering-an-array-with-a-function-that-returns-a-promise)
- [Map async functions over an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47826845/map-async-functions-over-an-array)

But I’m using TypeScript specifically with the intent of catching type errors like this at compile time. I’m surprised the compiler allows this code to pass at all.

Is there a TypeScript compiler setting or a linter that will catch this at compile time? I tried the default `tslint` configuration and it did not catch this.

Comment: Well it's not invalid per se, it just doesn't work well. I'm not sure there's a way except to create a wrapper function yourself that has these limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `filter()`, there is [similar open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19456). Note that there was a requirement for filter callback to return `boolean`, [but it was removed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5850#issuecomment-168878172) .

For `map()`, passing a callback that returns a promise is perfectly valid use case.